# Python's unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    dateadded = models.DateTimeField('date added')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

My problem is that `def _unicode_(self)` isn't working.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"?

Comment: fix the title as well...

Comment: All special methods in Python are surrounded by _double_ underscores on each side, not single. This is why they're called "dunder methods" instead of… "sunder methods"?

Comment: I'm using this to create a sample website, and on the website I have a table called Categorys.  When I go to add a new category and name it 'Books', it comes back naming it the generic 'category object' instead.  I'm pretty new to python, so I'm sorry if I'm not asking this properly.

Comment: Oh, double underscores instead of one.  I didn't even realize!  Can't believe it was that obvious.  Thank you so much for the quick replies!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use `def __unicode__`

Comment: Good answer, but it would be better if it explained the difference: you have _two_ underscores before and after the name, instead of _one_. (With a bad-enough font, it might be hard to see if you didn't know what you were looking for.)